# (MySQL) 2 foreign keys referencing the same table

Tags: mysql

On table transaction `c_acc` and `d_acc` are based on `account.id`

How can I achieve the query result as shown below?

The debit and credit in results table is auto summed up based on their type of account in table transaction, whether it's debit account or credit account. I was thinking of two joins `account a` and `account b` But I dont know how to implement it. I need help. Thank you!

**Table name: accounts**

```sql
+---------------------------+
|ID | account               |
|---+-----------------------|
|101| cash                  |
|---+-----------------------|
|102| accounts receivable   |
|---+-----------------------|
|103| notes receivable      |
|---+-----------------------|
|104| interest receivable   |
|---+-----------------------|
|105| merchandise inventory |
|---+-----------------------|
|201| accounts payable      |
+---------------------------+
```

**Table name: transaction**

```sql
+-----------------------------+
|ID|d_acc|c_acc|debit|credit  |
|--+-----+-----+-----+--------|
|1 |101  |102  |10000|10000   |
|--+-----+-----+-----+--------|
|2 |201  |101  |1000 |1000    |
|--+-----+-----+-----+--------|
|3 |101  |102  |300  |300     |
+-----------------------------+
```

**Query result**

```sql
+-----------------------------------+
|Account              |Debit|Credit |
|---------------------+-----+-------|
|Cash                 |10300|1000   |
|---------------------+-----+-------|
|accounts receivable  |     |10300  |
|---------------------+-----+-------|
|notes receivable     |     |       |
|---------------------+-----+-------|
|interest receivable  |     |       |
|---------------------+-----+-------|
|merchandise inventory|     |       |
|---------------------+-----+-------|
|accounts payable     |1000 |10000  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union 2 queries and group the results like this:

```
SELECT
x.account,
SUM(x.debit) AS debit,
SUM(x.credit) AS credit
FROM
(

SELECT
`accounts`.`account`,
`transaction`.`debit`,
0 AS `credit`
FROM
`accounts`
LEFT JOIN `transaction` ON (`accounts`.`ID`=`transaction`.`d_acc`)

UNION

SELECT
`accounts`.`account`,
0 AS `debit`,
`transaction`.`credit`
FROM
`accounts`
LEFT JOIN `transaction` ON (`accounts`.`ID`=`transaction`.`c_acc`)

) x
GROUP BY account
```

Note: I added backticks because 'transaction' is a reserved keyword

Comment: To see how it worked, just run the inner query. You'll see it will result in 2 sets, one set with only debit values (credit value=0) and one with only credit values (debit value=0).